# Why must I use gnu99 instead of c99 to compile a kernel module?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module, c99, gnu99

I am used to using `-std=c99` to enable c99 features when compiling application code.

Recently I have been following some basic kernel module examples, and added `ccflags-y := -std=c99` to the makefile. However this resulted in 17K lines of errors when I tried to make. `gnu99` works perfectly.

What is the difference between gnu99 and c99 that kernel code relies on?

Comment: +1. And you're not the first to notice. See http://llvm.linuxfoundation.org/

Comment: Basically, the kernel uses GCC extensions and does not compile when they are turned off.

Comment: `What is the difference between gnu99 and c99 that kernel code relies on?`. I think you can find these differences yourself. This is from gcc doc: `GNU C provides several language features not found in ISO standard C. (The -pedantic option directs GCC to print a warning message if any of these features is used.) `. So, build the kernel with `gnu99` but add `ccflags-y := -pedantic`. And then analyze warnings. This is from gcc's doc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions

Answer (score 1):

The linux kernel uses a lot of GCC extensions i.e., the C language used in the kernel is not standards compliant, it is a superset which includes GCC extension. Hence GNU99 is the compiler option which needs to be passed.

Comment: Actually, the Linux kernel itself is built using gnu89, not gnu99, because of semantic differences (such as the one discussed here: [http://www.kernelhub.org/?p=2&msg=606456](http://www.kernelhub.org/?p=2&msg=606456)). Hence, gnu89 should probably also be preferred as standard when making kernel modules, since included kernel-mode headers will likely rely on this standard.